# I am wanting to have text highligt in my help section when a user focuses on a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight

I have 2 divs, the first one has a form with input fields, the second is just a help section for password strength and such.  Here are my forms:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"  method="post" class="form-signin" id="reg_form" role="form" name="registration_form">
    Registration Key:<input class="form-control" type='text' name='reg_key' id='reg_key' required /><span id="loadergif"></span><br>
    Username:<input class="form-control" type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br>
    Email: <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br>
    Password:<input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" class="form-control input-group" type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br>
    Confirm password: <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return regformhash(this.form,this.form.username,this.form.email,this.form.password,this.form.confirmpwd);" /> <br>
    <p>Already registered? <a href="signin.php">Sign In</a></p>
</form>
```

and the help section:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="reg">Registration key can be found in the email that we sent you.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="user">Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="emailli">Emails must have a valid email format (e.g. test@test.com)</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="passfield">Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="passfield1">Passwords must contain:
        <ul>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="passfield2">At least one upper case letter (A..Z)</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="passfield3">At least one lower case letter (a..z)</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="passfield4">At least one number (0..9)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="confirmpass">Your password and confirmation must match exactly</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to use `$('#reg_key').focus($('#reg').addClass('highlight'));`, but all it does is just highlight each field no matter what. I would like for it to happen on focus then go to the next when a user focuses on the next field and remove the highlight from the previous one..

Update:

Here is what i applied:

```
$('#reg_key').focus(function(){
$('#reg').addClass('highlight');
});

$('#username').focus(function(){
$('#user').addClass('highlight');
$('#reg').removeClass('highlight');
});

$('#email').focus(function(){
$('#emailli').addClass('highlight');
$('#user').removeClass('highlight');
});

$('#password').focus(function(){
$('#passfield').addClass('highlight');
$('#passfield1').addClass('highlight');
$('#passfield2').addClass('highlight');
$('#passfield3').addClass('highlight');
$('#passfield4').addClass('highlight');
$('#emailli').removeClass('highlight');
});

$('#confirmpwd').focus(function(){
$('#confirmpass').addClass('highlight');
$('#passfield').removeClass('highlight');
$('#passfield1').removeClass('highlight');
$('#passfield2').removeClass('highlight');
$('#passfield3').removeClass('highlight');
$('#passfield4').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

but the #password and #confimpwd does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your HTML a bit. See if this works for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/91/

JS:

```
 $(document).on('focus','form input',function(){
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.list-group li.'+id).addClass('highlight');        
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" class="form-signin" id="reg_form" role="form" name="registration_form">Registration Key:
  <input class="form-control" type='text' name='reg_key' id='reg_key' required="true" /><span id="loadergif"></span>
  <br>Username:
  <input class="form-control" type='text' name='username' id='username' />
  <br>Email:
  <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  <br>Password:
  <input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" class="form-control input-group" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <br>Confirm password:
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" />
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return regformhash(this.form,this.form.username,this.form.email,this.form.password,this.form.confirmpwd);" />
  <br>
  <p>Already registered? <a href="signin.php">Sign In</a>
  </p>
</form>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item reg_key">Registration key can be found in the email that we sent you.</li>
  <li class="list-group-item username">Usernames may contain only digits, upper and lower case letters and underscores</li>
  <li class="list-group-item email">Emails must have a valid email format (e.g. test@test.com)</li>
  <li class="list-group-item password">Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</li>
  <li class="list-group-item confirmpwd">Passwords must contain:
<ul>
        <li class="list-group-item passfield2">At least one upper case letter (A..Z)</li>
        <li class="list-group-item passfield3">At least one lower case letter (a..z)</li>
        <li class="list-group-item passfield4">At least one number (0..9)</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item confirmpass">Your password and confirmation must match exactly</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using Id, used classes to associate input and the message fields.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just asking, why don't you have uniform edges in your form inputs in the link? I am talking about border-radius here?

Comment: why is the ul up higher? I am not sure.  I am still developing the site and such. That is a weird one though...

Comment: ul is higher because you have given padding to form in the left div. If you need uniform level then give same padding to right div.

Comment: And instead of giving individual border-radius, you could use form input{border-radius:4px;} or better give a common class to all the inputs where you want the round corner.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have coded this will cause your `.addClass` statement to execute immediately. You need to wrap that statement in an anonymous function to delay it until the element has been focused:

```
$('#reg_key').focus(function(){
   $('#reg').addClass('highlight')
});
```

Comment: You probably also want to unhighlight it on blur with similar calls to "blur" and "removeClass".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, to add the highlight class to current help field and remove it for the previous one:

```
$('#currentinputelementID').focus(function(){
   $('#currenthelpfieldID').addClass('highlight');
   $('#previoushelpfieldID').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an alternative solution using the `:focus` pseudo-selector, here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/Qxxtb/

### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"/><br/>
    <input type="password" id="password"/>
    <div>
        <p data-for="name">this is the help for name</p>
        <p data-for="password">this is the help for password</p>
    </div>    
</form>
```

### CSS

```
#name:focus ~ div > p[data-for="name"],
#password:focus ~ div > p[data-for="password"]{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```